# Why C# Server Object Extensions are faster

Tags: arcgis-server, performance, server-object-extension

From my experience C# SOE are the fastest. It is also discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74817/has-anybody-done-performance-benchmarks-between-c-c-and-java-arcgis-server).

ArcGIS Server is developed in Java, how come .NET is the fastest?

Comment: Would you be able to quantify that experience in any way?  If not, then I suspect that your question will be too broad and open to opinions because speed can be measured in many ways.  By making your question about a specific test, which you describe, it will enable your question to qualify as focussed Q&A.